# PowerShell to check if service is disabled

Tags: windows, powershell

Below is a function to ensure services are set to the correct startup type. My question is how to script this to account for a service not existing? For example, if I am okay with "Name of Service 2" either being disabled OR not existing, I do not want an error to return. What change needs made to the code?

```bsh
function validate-services {

    $servicelist = @{    

    "Name of Service 1" = "Manual"
    "Name of Service 2" = "Disabled"

    }

    foreach ($service in $servicelist.Keys){ 

        $startType = (Get-Service -Name $service).StartType

        if ( $startType -eq $servicelist[$service] ){

            write-host $service "is correct." 
        } 
        else
        {
            write-host $service "is NOT set to the correct startup type."            
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try catching the error of a missing service?

Comment: No, how would you recommend doing that?

Comment: Took me far too long to spot the missing `"` to fix the syntax highlighting :D

Comment: @Joseph - i would make your test more flexible by NOT embedding the two services and their states in the function. make those parameters and have the function return a `False/True` or a PSCO that holds the service, wanted starttype, actual starttype, a final `IsCorrect` property. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encapsulate the part that may throw an exception in a `try` block and add the reaction to that exception into a following `catch` block:

```bsh
function Validate-Services {

    $servicelist = @{    
        "Name of Service 1" = "Manual"
        "Name of Service 2" = "Disabled"
    }

    foreach ($service in $servicelist.Keys) { 
        try {
            $startType = (Get-Service -Name $service -ErrorAction Stop).StartType
            if ($startType -eq $servicelist[$service]) {
                Write-Host "$service is correct." 
            } else {
                Write-Host "$service is NOT set to the correct startup type."            
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Host "$service does not exist."
        }
    } 
}
```